# How to see when I performed the upgrade to 19.04

Tags: upgrade

I upgraded this machine to 19.04 sometime just before the official release. I want now to track down the start of an issue I'm having and need to know when I did that.

The top line of /var/log/apt/history.log seems likely but I don't see anything really convincing.

What would I look for?

Comment: Did you use the terminal or the GUI?

Comment: @DKBose Terminal: `do-release-upgrade`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the date by looking in */var/log/dist-upgrade/history.log*. But a more "behind-the-scenes" and informative file is */var/log/dist-upgrade/main.log*.